# Removing link border only from links that are images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two links (one a text link and one an image link): [see image](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s21/sh/303c4106-e774-495e-ab15-baf8fb636d28/82a525bbd03acc68431ce9c82e6760b1/deep/0/Quality-Tips.png)

How would I go about removing the border-bottom style for links that are images but keep them for links that are texts

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #28c3ab;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #28c3ab;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to remove the border from some links.

CSS:

```
a.img {
    border: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">This has a border</a>
<a class="img" href="#"><img sc="" alt="No border" /></a>
```

Comment: Awesome. I was trying to do that but my css syntax was off.  I put a space like "a .img" instead of no space as you did: "a.img"

Comment: You were darn close! :) `a img` could be used to target an `<img>` element with a parent `<a>` element -- but couldn't work in this case, because it's the `<a>` element itself that has the border.